# How to validate a bitcoin transaction

Tags: transaction-verification

Sorry for the noob question, but I just installed bitcoin core last week and am running a full node.

I want to verify a transaction I sent to a new coldcard wallet.  How do I do this in core?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see whether a transaction sending money to a cold wallet is received. You should be able to use an application provided for use with the cold wallet or just check the transaction ID and receiving address in any blockchain explorer. You could also add the address to any wallet as a watch-only address.

If you have a draft transaction in raw hex and want to see if it looks OK you might try some of the RPC APIs, maybe [testmempoolaccept](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/rpc/testmempoolaccept.html)

> Returns result of mempool acceptance tests indicating if raw transaction (serialized, hex-encoded) would be accepted by mempool.
>
> This checks if the transaction violates the consensus or policy rules.